# Grep use to extract word with special character

Tags: linux, bash

I want to grep line.
Example I have #chargen  in file and i want to command to grep output this word with #

```
cat /etc/inetd.conf | grep '*#' chargen
```

no result, any idea

Comment: i use this command cat /etc/inetd.conf | grep '#'chargen but i recive
 #chargen        stream  tcp     nowait  root    internal
#chargen        dgram   udp     wait    root    internal , i want only output #chargen

Comment: [Useless use of cat?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/608639) and [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: `grep -Eo '#[[:alnum:]]+'`

Comment: or `grep -o '#chargen'`